# Equivalent of code coverage for selenium test

Tags: coverage, test-report

I'm currently writing test using cucumber + selenium. I will also write tests for web services (using SoapUI) and my chief would like to have a quick and clear view of what fonctionnality/feature is covered by test and what isn't.

**So, I was wondering if something similar to code coverage (for unit test) exist?** And, if not, how can I present the test that I have done in a "clean" way?

So far, I have just try to write a word document who, for each web page, explain in one or two lines which tests were made. And there is also the option of making an excel document with one line for each test. But my chief isn't really a good fan of thoses solutions (not clear and visual enought it seems).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same approach as they do with unit tests. Code coverage tools allow you to instrument the build of your app under test. So the process would look lie the following:

1. You build your app
2. You apply instrumentation to your build
3. You deploy that build and run your selenium tests against that build
4. Then you execute reporting feature of a tool and it builds you the report of which code lines have been covered and which not.

The tools are different for different programming languages. If your app is written in Java you can use [JaCoCo tool](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/index.html).

Comment: can you please help regarding instrumentation?

Comment: @vaibhavcool20 https://www.webelement.click/en/code_coverage_with_jacoco_and_existing_jar_application